# Rails 4: Unexpected slowdowns in view rendering and ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nginx

I am developing application on Rails and have troubles with performance. Below I have described and provided all technologies, configurations and methods I used. I tried many methods to solve this problem but nothing helped. This is also described below. Can anyone see what the problem is? Thank you!

### The problem

Let's open site several times and see log:
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 171ms (Views: 149.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 183.7ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 221ms (Views: 188.2ms | ActiveRecord: 11.7ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 165ms (Views: 143.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)`
Fine.

Now let's generate load with `wrk -t10 -c10 -d10s http://example.com` and see log again:
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 178ms (Views: 157.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.1ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 270ms (Views: 241.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 505ms (Views: 460.7ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 501ms (Views: 350.8ms | ActiveRecord: 136.0ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 777ms (Views: 468.1ms | ActiveRecord: 269.1ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 936ms (Views: 624.7ms | ActiveRecord: 285.1ms)`
`...`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 881ms (Views: 617.4ms | ActiveRecord: 251.6ms)`
`...`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3289ms (Views: 2614.2ms | ActiveRecord: 326.4ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3369ms (Views: 2624.0ms | ActiveRecord: 409.4ms)`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3203ms (Views: 2369.2ms | ActiveRecord: 382.1ms)`
`...`
`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 281.1ms | ActiveRecord: 126.3ms)`
`...`
What are this terrible slowdowns?

```
wrk -t10 -c10 -d10s http://example.com
Running 10s test @ http://example.com
  10 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.26s    96.38ms   1.39s    75.00%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00    100.00%
  36 requests in 10.09s, 0.97MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 32
Requests/sec:      3.57
Transfer/sec:     98.62KB
```

### Rails

I am using latest Rails version - 4.2.4.
`bundle list` output - [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/684340f4123e82712bf1)
`application.rb` - [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/f7bcd66336a45a97b844)
`production.rb` - [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/3726271767f839b21297)
`database.yml` - [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/9b611614a6fd3b4fa320)

I am using [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) for all my models. (`WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`)

All N+1 queries are eliminated (analyzed them manually and with [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet)).
All tables are InnoDB and have a lot of indices. 99% of tables have 50 or less rows, the rest 1% - 200 or less. That's very low amount of data.

Page I am benchmarking requires around 30-35 SQL queries and around 30 partials.
Queries using...
- COUNT    - 0
- GROUP BY - 1
- ORDER BY - 10
- LIMIT    - 10
- JOIN     - 1 (joins one table)
- Use of MAX, MIN, CONCAT and other functions - NO

My templates are written in [Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim).

### Server configuration

CPU - Intel one core Sandy Bridge CPU
RAM - 1GM
Disk Type - SSD

### Operating System

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

Swap 1GB. Optimized swap settings:
`cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness => 10`
`cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure => 50`

### Database

MySQL 5.5. Tried to optimize with mysqltuner and tuning-primer.
Current configuration: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/81cace00ea9a1b3d1927)

Latest mysqltuner report: `perl mysqltuner.pl --buffers --dbstat --outputfile result_mysqltuner.txt` [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/ab5ef16cec4e454cec06)

Latest tuning-primer report: `./tuning-primer.sh` [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/680f966d1c72e3ee4ce5)

I have notices the warning `Temporary tables created on disk`. That's because I have TEXT columns in MySQL. Googling I found that mounting MySQL temporary directory in memory is good idea. So I did it: `tmpdir /var/mysqltmp`. Followed [this guide](http://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html).

`mytop output`:

```
 Queries: 37.4k    qps:    0 Slow:    1.9k         Se/In/Up/De(%):    91/00/00/00
 Sorts:     0 qps now:    1 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:    4 (   1/   2) 00/00/00/00
 Cache Hits: 29.0k Hits/s:  0.4 Hits now:   0.0  Ratio: 85.5%
 Ratio now:  0.0%
 Key Efficiency: 99.4%  Bps in/out:  75.8/ 1.9k   Now in/out:  22.6/ 2.1k

       Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query
       --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------
     1444      root       localhost site             73737   Sleep
     2337      root       localhost site             658     Sleep
     2340      root       localhost site             322     Sleep
     2342      root       localhost                  0       Query         show full processlist
```

### Ruby interpreter

Rbenv: `rbenv -v => rbenv 0.4.0-154-g9e664b5`
Ruby: `ruby -v => ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]`

My ruby is compiled with jemalloc (better memory allocation):
`RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS'] => "-lpthread -ljemalloc -ldl -lcrypt -lm "`
Followed [this guide](http://groguelon.fr/post/106221222318/how-to-install-ruby-220-with-jemalloc-support).

I have tried both ruby with default and custom memory allocation. Ruby with jemalloc seems to be faster.

### Web server

`nginx -v => nginx version: nginx/1.8.0`
Current nginx.conf (simplified):  [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/60fe6a9f29abe34f5469)
Current nginx site conf (simplified): [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/64dfb7b8d17a3a265203)

### Application server

I have tried both Passenger and Puma. But without result.

#### Phusion Passenger

`passenger -v => Phusion Passenger version 5.0.18`
Configuration: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/b63c610c3fc0882be85b)

#### Puma

`bundle exec puma -v => puma version 2.13.4`
Also I have tried Puma server in both cluster (1 worker) and thread models.
Here is latest config for Puma in thread mode: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/yivo/ee777d47110fe980b225)

Comment: Did you tried use some benchmarking tools and inspect which view partial or Controller/Model method is slow?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to change the number of connections open.  I noticed in quite a few examples of using wrk that the thread count to connections count is 5:1.  It is probably to give the server some time to respond.  Try upping the connection count to 50when thread count is 10 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @nayiaw, yes of course. I tried rack-mini-profiler, NewRelic and SkyLight. When page gets load all views become slow.

Comment: @BasselSamman, still terrible slow.

Comment: Okay,   what exactly is slow?  I read and re-read you description, but the only thing I can come up with is a blanket statement of joins are slow.  Not that it is actually your problem.  Have you tried chrome panel?  It is a chrome extension the uses meta_request gem to show you exactly what happened when a page is loaded and  how much time each part took, including all sql queries.  Try it out and find out what is slow.  Then we can go from there.

Comment: sorry, I meant the chrome rails panel extension.  Here is the link to point you to the goodness:  https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel